# Lodge 12sk lid, what can I use?

Tags: cast-iron, skillet

I have Lodge 12sk(13") skillet. I would like to find a lid, glass or stainless steel, the lodge cast iron lid is too heavy for my spouse. And recommendations would be appreciated.

I was thinking that an inverted Norpro 5672 pizza pan may work, but I don't have one to try. Does anyone have a 12sk and Norpro pan they could try?

Thanks

Comment: Odd.  Lodge now has a 15" glass cover ... but not a 13" one.

Answer (score 2):

I often use a baking sheet. Not pretty, but it works. Combine with foil for a tighter seal.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of companies that make 'universal lids', where it's effectively a series of steps at different diameters, such that it'll center itself well on a variety of sizes of pans.

(being well centered can be important if you have significant steam generation; a centered lid might pop up as steam escapes, but will tend to settle back down on the pan ... an uncentered lid might slowly wiggle its way off the pan)

I can't comment on any of the current ones on the market -- I had one back in college that was just cheap aluminum.  I gave it away when I got a set of pots as a hand me down that all had their own matching lids.

I'd personally steer clear of glass lids if there's a chance of the glass coming into contact with the pan itself (and not just a center insert around an otherwise metal lid).  Tempered glass can fail destructively after too many hits, and a bubbling pot can cause the lid to repeatedly tap against the edge of the pan.

Comment: Like this one: [Universal Lid](http://smile.amazon.com/Norpro-627-Smart-Universal-Lid/dp/B0063QEI26/ref=sr_1_2?s=home-garden&ie=UTF8&qid=1436851096&sr=1-2&keywords=universal+lid) I haven't used it either, but the reviews are excellent.